# Mongodb/Node.js findByIdAndUpdate method not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to update a collection in my mongo database using the findByIdAndUpdate method. I hit the endpoint and the request with the updated information gets sent, by the response is always the information before the update and the update never appears in my database.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is my edit.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');
const dbConfig = require('../mongo/dbConfig');
const Band = require('../mongo/models/band');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


// Initialize the router
const router = express.Router();
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.devUrl);

//init body parser
router.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);

router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/band/editProfile', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log("it hit !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  Band.findByIdAndUpdate(
    // the id of the item to find

   req.body.id,
    {
      bands: {
        bandName: req.body.bandName,
        genre: req.body.genre,
        numberOfMembers: req.body.numberOfMembers,
        city: req.body.city,
        state: req.body.state,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        travel: req.body.travel,
        travelDistance: req.body.travelDistance,
        spotify: req.body.spotify,
        youtube: req.body.youtube,
        soundcloud: req.body.soundcloud,
        twitter: req.body.twitter,
        facebook: req.body.facebook
      }
    },
    function (err, response) {
      // Handle any possible database errors
      if (err) {
        console.log("we hit an error" + err);
        res.json({
          message: 'Database Update Failure'
        });
      }
      console.log("This is the Response: " + response);
    }
  );
});
```

here is my Band model:

```
//Module Imports
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Initializes a mongoose schema to be used with the document
const bandSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  bandName: String,
  genre: String,
  numberOfMembers: Number,
  city: String,
  state: String,
  zip: String,
  travel: Boolean,
  travelDistance: Number,
  spotify: String,
  youtube: String,
  soundcloud: String,
  twitter: String,
  facebook: String
});

//Creates the Schema to be used with the export
let Band = mongoose.model('band', bandSchema);

//Exports the Schema to the API
module.exports = Band;
```

I've researched this pretty thoroughly and am stuck so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bands` is in your update object, but not in your schema. Just remove that extra layer of your update object and the update should work. But you also need to include the `{new: true}` option as a separate parameter so that the updated document is returned instead of the original (see [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate)).

```
Band.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.body.id,
  {
    bandName: req.body.bandName,
    genre: req.body.genre,
    numberOfMembers: req.body.numberOfMembers,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    travel: req.body.travel,
    travelDistance: req.body.travelDistance,
    spotify: req.body.spotify,
    youtube: req.body.youtube,
    soundcloud: req.body.soundcloud,
    twitter: req.body.twitter,
    facebook: req.body.facebook
  },
  {new: true},
  function (err, response) {
    // Handle any possible database errors
    if (err) {
      console.log("we hit an error" + err);
      res.json({
        message: 'Database Update Failure'
      });
    }
    console.log("This is the Response: " + response);
  }
);
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!